# TCP flags combination

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

Is the following combination of TCP flags possible ? I mean, can a packet have these flags on in a network traffic?

[PAE]

If yes, then in what situations? If no, then why?

Thank you.

Comment: You can send a TCP segment (not packet) with any combination of flags. Some combinations don't really make much sense, but that doesn't mean you can't send a segment with any combination. You should check [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) for the combinations which make sense, and the combinations which don't make sense.

Comment: nmap sends NULL probes (TCP packets with all flags off) and FULL probes (all flags on) in some scenarios.  Both are invalid according to the RFCs but exist in the real world.  Since different OSes answer differently, it is one of the ways to guess the running OS on the remote system.